# retrofit illegal argument exception

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Can anyone help me with this retrofit statement:

```
"/tables/PyylonRegistration?Login={login}&Password={password}"
```

I tried to post query from Android and it still throws `illegal argument exception`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED 
In case anyone needs here is the way it worked:

@POST("/tables/PyylonRegistration?Login=login&Password=password")
    RegistrationResult register(@Header("authorization")String authorization, @Query("Login")String login, @Query("Password")String password);